# Remote connecting to Ubuntu 18.04 from Windows Remote Desktop: "login failed for display 0"

Tags: xorg, windows-8, xrdp

I have installed xRDP and supposedly activated it properly.
I know the name and IP address of my remote Ubuntu.

When I do get a connection through Windows RDP I am presented with a log-in screen and a choice of servers. I choose Xorg and X11RDP, and neither accepts my credentials. I am logged off the Ubuntu because I have read being logged in might be a problem.

Should I be setting up Xorg on the Ubuntu? Should I be providing same credentials remotely and I do when I access Ubuntu locally?

Here's a picture of the connection log:

[image: connecting to sesman ip 127.0.0.1 port 3350 / sesman connect ok / sending login info to session manager, please wait... / login failed for display 0]

Answer (score 1):

when posting question, please always specify complete version of the Ubuntu Operating system.   if you are using Ubuntu 18.04.3 (you can check this by typing the following command in a terminal console (lsb_release -sd), this might be a known issue....

Ubuntu 18.04.2 and 18.04.3 are using a new xorg-xserver-xorg-hwe* packages that prevent the installation of the xorgxrdp components of xrdp package.....

**Best option -  Install the new xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04 package**

Install the new xorgxrdp package by issuing the following command

> sudo apt-get install xorgxrdp-hwe-18.04

This should fix your issue

**Dirty fix - Downgrade to previous xorg-xserver-xorg packages**

*We assume that you have already installed xRDP package and you want to fix it*

> sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
>
> sudo apt-get -y install xserver-xorg-input-all

More info on http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13390

**Other option - use one of the xrdp installer script**

*Note : To use this option, please remove the xrdp package you have installed*

You can automate the xrdp installation and have it working nicely with Ubuntu Default Desktop using one of the following scripts

> To use Ubuntu repository packages, read instructions and download the
>   script at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13933
>
> To compile from source (easy way), read instructions and download the
>   script at
>   http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=13663 Hope this help Till next time See ya

Hope this help

Till next time